# Fragment Animation: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) Crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm encountering **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)** and UI issues on some Android devices when I use animation, on `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations`

My Setup (Nested Fragments):
[image]

A: My main fragment
F1, F2: Flow Fragments, either of them gets added in Main Fragment A
F11, F12, F13... Fragments which gets added/removed to Flow Fragment F1
F21, F22, F23... Fragments which gets added/removed to Flow Fragment F2

I've applied simple Slide In/Out transitions.
According to my observations, crash occurs in this scenario:

- I've pressed Back from F12
- Transition F12 to F11 in in progress in F1 Container
- At the same time I press a button on A which triggers transition of replacing F1 with F2

Did anyone encountered this before? Please help me, struggling with this since 3 days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185457) in Android's Support Lib and resolved in versions 23.0.1 and above.